# Excel Stacked area chart with 4 series - how to make it vertically drop or start

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have month wise expenses for the whole year. Each month, I might have actual data.

For example, in January, all month's data will be forecast. Once we are in Feb, January's actual data will come in and forecast will go away. And for Feb-Dec, there will be only forecast data.

So, at any point, for any month, there will either be forecast data or actual data - not both.

[image: Data]

When I plot a stacked area chart, I tried ways to avoid the diagonal drop when actual changes to forecast. But couldn't find a solution.

I tried using dynamic name range using OFFSET function and used that in the series, but got a result like this:

[image: Graph]

How do I ensure that the forecast series starts plotting from May and not Jan?

Answer (score 1):

After inserting the chart (in the example I've used a simple area chart, not stacked area):

- right click on it and "select data"
- click "hidden and empty cells"
- select "gaps" for "show empty cells as" and press OK

[image]

### Update

It seems that "show empty cells as gaps" is disable for stacked area chart, please use a non-stacked area chart.

To remove gap between the two series you need to enter data in both columns for one month:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but Gaps is greyed out in my graph. I only have the Zero option. Also, I would like the transition from actual to forecast go on without a gap.

Comment: @user693204: thanks for the feedback, please see my updated answer.